# Conkeror does not prompt to remember passwords

Tags: browser, conkeror

I've been using conkeror for a while, and at some point password management stopped working.  Conkeror no longer displays a prompt offering to remember new passwords; existing passwords can still be edited with M-x password-manager but conkeror no longer automatically fills out the passwords for any of the websites that I tried.

I have tried using a new empty profile with a minimal rc file containing just the required password management code suggested on the conkeror wiki (http://conkeror.org/PasswordManagement):

```
session_pref("signon.rememberSignons", true);
session_pref("signon.expireMasterPassword", false);
session_pref("signon.SignonFileName", "signons.txt");
Cc["@mozilla.org/login-manager;1"].getService(Ci.nsILoginManager); // init
```

The version is Conkeror 1.0pre on Xulrunner 25.0.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla recently introduced [changes to XULRunner's password manager](https://blog.mozilla.org/dolske/2013/08/21/a-change-in-password-manager/).  This means you need to [update your configuration](https://github.com/thorkill/config-conkeror/blob/master/dot.conkerorrc/100-login.js).